# Processing for Android, use of libraries

Tags: java, android, processing

I have a Processing sketch that works fine on my computer.

I'm now trying to get it running on my Android tablet using Processing Android mode. But I'm getting a lot of compiler errors saying "cannot find symbol".

I'm using some Processing libraries I've created using https://github.com/processing/processing-library-template .

These libraries don't actually access system resources or call the Processing library themselves. Or any other external Java except Java.util. They're just manipulating data-structures.

However it seems Android mode has a problem with them.

Googling around it seems that a lot of Processing libraries don't work with Android Mode, but I can't find anything explicit : should I simply assume that external libraries can't work at all with Android mode? Or are there specific things that won't work? Or should I be looking for a specific bug somewhere in my code?

Update : Further details. I believe Processing Android mode targets Android 2.3.3. I'm using Processing 2.21. The libraries I'm talking about are my own.

Comment: which version of Processing, which version(s) of Android, and which versions of which libraries? (Please update your post with that information =)

Comment: Care to provide the compiler output? Then we could see which symbols cannot be found.

Comment: Could you give us a short snippet of the error logs to have a better understanding.

Comment: Can you compile your utility to a jar and copy it to the lib directory on the android device (this may be wrong, as I don't know very much about java on android)

Comment: @interstar Please provide us the error. Also, did you try one of the releases?

Answer (score 3):

From a [related](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/106) Git Issue page , a comment by [omerjerk](https://github.com/omerjerk)

> The master branch of this repository is not buildable with the master
>   branch of processing. processing has moved ahead and we haven't
>   updated this repository yet.  Why are you really building the Android
>   mode yourself ? **If you want to run your processing sketches on your
>   phone, then just download `processing 2.2.1` from the main website, open
>   the IDE and from there, download the Android mode. In case, if you
>   really want to build Android mode from source, apply this pull request
>   - [#98](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/pull/98) .**

See if this helps

Comment: Thanks. To be clear. I AM able to get Processing running on my tablet. The problem is that I can't use a library that I compiled and packaged as a Processing Library (using the Processing Library Template) 

My work-around has been to just copy all the source-code of the library directly into my Processing sketch where it compiles perfectly and runs OK on Android. Similarly, when running in Java mode, the packaged libraries. work. It's some incompatibility with the Android-Processing and the Processing Libraries.

Comment: I see, error logs would be really useful, provide them, also ensure build.properties is correct. In general the error is possibly there.